# Synchronization on "reference" or on instance

Tags: java, synchronization

Consider the following code:

```
public class Foo {
  private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
  private Object _lockRef1 = LOCK;
  private Object _lockRef2 = LOCK;
  private int _indx = 0;

  public void dec() {
    synchronized(_lockRef1) {
      _indx--;
    }
  }

  public void inc() {
    synchronized(_lockRef2) {
      _indx++;
    }
  }
}
```

Is call to methods `dec()` and `inc()` threadsafe? On the one hand these methods are synchronized on two different instances _`lockRef1` and _`lockRef2`. On the other hand, these instances "point" on the same object `LOCK`...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They're not "synchronized on two different instances" - just because you use two different *variables* doesn't mean there are two different *instances*. You've got several variables each of which will have the same value - a reference to the single instance of `java.lang.Object`.

So yes, this is thread-safe. Of course you shouldn't write code like this in terms of readability, but assuming you're just trying to understand what happens, it's fine.

Comment: The question is tagged 'Java', so I think this would be `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @Yuval: Doh - didn't spot that. Thanks, fixed :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Actually, I have an emun instead of "private static final Object", but it seems the idea is the same.

Comment: @Marcus: Well I agree with them - your question looks like it's a duplicate of this one. You certainly haven't made it clear *why* it's not a duplicate.